# mac os - how to remove "Macintosh HD" from path?

Tags: macos

Third party app (Photoshop) returns (via Photoshop api) path with "Macintosh HD" at the beginning:

```
/Macintosh HD/Users/alek/Documents/renderly-example.psd
```

What I need is path without `Macintosh HD`

```
/Users/alek/Documents/renderly-example.psd
```

How I can safely strip `Macintosh HD` from path? By safely I mean to remove it always even if it it's value is different (like `John HD`). How I can normalize such path assuming that it MAY or MAY NOT contain `Macintosh HD` "prefix" in the path?

So for both paths

```
/Macintosh HD/Users/alek/Documents/renderly-example.psd
```

AND

```
/Users/alek/Documents/renderly-example.psd
```

result should be:

```
/Users/alek/Documents/renderly-example.psd
```

Comment: What language? Bash? Applescript? Javascript?

Comment: node.js but I have access to shell

Answer (score 1):

I think I would go with something like this:

```
#!/bin/bash
# Get name of system startup disk - in case user has changed it
startupdisk=$(osascript -e 'tell application "Finder" to set startup_Disk to (name of startup disk)')
# Make path absolute
absstartup="/$startupdisk"
# Remove this from whatever the user provided as a parameter
echo ${1/$absstartup/}
```

Save that as `normalizepath` and make it executable with

```
chmod +x normalizepath
```

and then run with

```
./normalizepath "/Macintosh HD/Users/alek/Documents/renderly-example.psd"
```

It basically asks the Finder for the path to the startup disk, just in case the user has renamed it away from `Macintosh HD`, and then adds a slash on the front to make it absolute and then removes whatever results from that off the front of the supplied parameter.